# An inequality about condition number and LU decomposition.

Tags: inequality, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $P(A+E)=LU$, where $P$ is a permutation, $L$ is lower triangular with $|l_{ij}|\le1$,and $U$ is upper triangular. Show that
$$\kappa_{\infty}(A)\ge\frac{\|A\|_{\infty}}{\|E\|_{\infty}+\min|u_{ii}|}$$
Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos;Thank you, I know, I will pay attention next time, and I have now solved this problem.